# AngularJs delete record on nested grouped rows with pagination

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to build a simple page to group record and then add a button to eliminate some records.

The problem is that if the record eliminated is the first, all the grouped data will be deleted.

I think the problem is when I split the grouped array:

Plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/DiO0tiPWeyRDGCoeHpdW?p=preview

```
$scope.deleteItem = function(item,row){ 

  var index=$scope.reports.indexOf(item)
  $scope.reports.splice(index,1); 
  $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.reports.length / $scope.pageSize);
  $scope.pages.then(function(result){
  result.splice(index,1);

  $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil(result.length / $scope.pageSize);
                $scope.currentPage = 1; 
                console.log(result)
  })
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mainly doing 2 things wrong:

1. trying to erase the same index in result as you are in reports
2. erasing in result while there are more items in that row.

A possible (working) fix for this will be:

```
$scope.deleteItem = function(item,row){ 

  var lastInRow = true;
  var index=$scope.reports.indexOf(item);
  $scope.reports.splice(index,1);

  //check if any more items match that name (or in the same row)
  for (var i=0; i<$scope.reports.length; ++i) {
    if ($scope.reports[i].name == item.name) {
      lastInRow = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.reports.length / $scope.pageSize);

  $scope.pages.then(function(result){
      //get the relevant index for the result array
      var resultIndex = result.indexOf(item.name);

      //if it matches and it isn't the last one - erase that row
      if (result && result[index] == item.name && lastInRow) {
        result.splice(resultIndex,1);  
      }
                $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil(result.length / $scope.pageSize);
                $scope.currentPage = 1; 
        })
};
```